# Eigenvalues in orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\Bbb R)$.
How can I prove, that

> **1)** if $ \forall {b \in \Bbb R^n}, b^{t}Ab>0$, then all eigenvalues $>0$.
>    **2)** if $A$ is orthogonal, then all eigenvalues are equal to $-1$ or $1$

Comment: for two use the fact that you can diagonalize orthogonal matrices and the determinant of orthogonal matrices is 1

Comment: Two is false. The _determinant_ is $\pm 1$, not the eigenvalues in general. Take a rotation matrix for example.

Comment: 1) does not need to to be true if $A$ is not symmetric. In that case, you could construct a real matrix with complex eigenvalues satisfying (1) but obviously with non-real eigenvalues (though their real parts might be positive).

Comment: @Ale The link you give has counter-examples in it. The eigenvalues merely have to satisfy $|\lambda| = 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(1):**

Let $Av=\lambda v$ with $v\not=0$, i.e. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Then 
$$0<v^t Av=\lambda v^t v=\lambda \|v\|^2.$$

Since $\|v\|^2>0$, we get $\lambda>0$.

**(2):**

You certainly mean that the determinant of $A$ is $\pm 1$, since the statement about the eigenvalues is not true, for consider the orthogonal matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

This represents a rotation and has therefore complex eigenvalues.

But if $A$ is orthogonal, then $A^tA=AA^t=I$, therefore applying the $\det$ to both sides and using the multiplication law for determinants, we obtain

$$(\det A)^2 = 1$$

Therefore $\det A=\pm 1$.

Comment: This solution has problems. $|\lambda|=1$ holds for the eigenvalues of every orthogonal matrix Q.

Answer (score 34):

Let $\lambda$ be $A$ eigenvalue and $Ax=\lambda{x}$.

> **(1)** ${x}^{t}Ax=\lambda{x^tx}>0.$ Because $x^tx>0$, then $\lambda>0$
>
> **(2)** $|\lambda|^2x^tx=(Ax)^{t}Ax={x}^{t}A^{t}Ax=x^tx.$ So $|\lambda|=1$. Then $\lambda=e^{i\phi}$ for some $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$; i.e. all the eigenvalues lie on the unit circle.

Comment: If $|\lambda|=1$, it does not follow that $\lambda=\pm 1$. Only $\lambda=e^{i\phi}$ for some real $\phi$.

Comment: Yes, you are very right.@TooOldForMath You must consider the real eigenvalue.

Answer (score 15):

The first part of the problem is well solved above, so I want to emphasize on the second part, which was partially solved.

An orthogonal transformation is either a rotation or a reflection. I will focus on 3D which has  lots of practical use. Let us then assume that $A$ is an orthonormal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$.

We find that its eigenvalues are either $1, \text{e}^{\pm i \theta}$ for a rotation or $\pm 1$ for a reflection.

1. **For a rotation:** 
   We have the following sequence of equalities (since $\det A = 1$)

   \begin{eqnarray*}    \det(I -A) &=& \det(A) \det (I-A)  \\   &=&
   \det(A^T) \det(I-A)  \\   &=&  \det(A^T - I)  \\   &=&  \det(A - I) 
   \\   &=& -\det(I-A)   \quad , \text{since 3 is odd}, \end{eqnarray*}
   So $\det(I-A)=0$ and $\lambda_1=1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

   Now, let $u_1$ the unit eigenvector of $\lambda_1$, so $A u_1 =
   u_1$.  We show that the matrix $A$ is a rotation of an angle
   $\theta$  around this axis $u_1$. Let us form a new coordinate
   system using $u_1, u_2, u_1 \times u_2$, where $u_2$ is a vector
   orthogonal to $u_1$, so the new system is right handed (has
   determinant = 1). The transformation between the old system $\{e_1,
   e_2, e_3\}$ and the new system is given by a matrix  $B$ with column
   vectors $u_1, u_2$, and $u_3$.  So we have that $B e_i = u_i$. Let
   us call the coordinate transformation (similarity) matrix $C =
   B^{-1}AB$. Then 
   \begin{eqnarray*} 
       C e_1 = B^{-1} A B e_1 = B^{-1} A u_1 = B^{-1} u_1 = e_1.  \end{eqnarray*}  The fact that $C e_1 = e_1$ means two things:

   - The first column of $C$ is  $(1,0,0)^T$.
   - The first raw of $C$ is $(1,0,0)$.

   Then $C$ is a matrix of the type 
   \begin{eqnarray*}  
   C = \left (   \begin{array}{ccc}
       1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & a & b \\
       0 & c & d \\   \end{array}   \right ) \end{eqnarray*}  Since $A$ is orthogonal $C$ is orthogonal and so the vectors $(a,c)^T$ and
   $(b,d)^T$  are orthogonal and since  \begin{eqnarray*}
       1 = \theta A = \det C = ad - bc  \end{eqnarray*} we have that the minor matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$ is a rotation (orthogonal 
   with determinat 1). Rotations in 2D are of the form
   \begin{eqnarray*}
       \left (
       \begin{array}{cc}
         a  & b \\
         c  & d 
       \end{array}
       \right )
   =
       \left (
       \begin{array}{cc}
         \cos \theta  & -\sin \theta \\
         \sin \theta  & \cos \theta 
       \end{array}
       \right ) \end{eqnarray*} then   \begin{eqnarray*}   B^{-1}A B = \left (   \begin{array}{ccc}
       1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
       0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta    \end{array}   \right ) \end{eqnarray*} But since the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}AB$ are the same
   as those of $A$ we find the eigenvalues of this matrix and those
   would be the eigenvalues of $A$.

   For the eigenvalues of this matrix we have that

   \begin{eqnarray*}   \det ( C - \lambda I)= 0 \implies   (\cos \theta
   - \lambda)^2 + \sin^2 \theta = 0. \end{eqnarray*} That is,

   \begin{eqnarray*} 1 -2 \lambda \cos \theta + \lambda^2 = 0
   \end{eqnarray*} Then

   \begin{eqnarray*}   \lambda = \frac{2 \cos \theta \pm \sqrt{4 \cos^2
   \theta - 4}}{2} =  \cos \theta \pm i \sin \theta = \text{e}^{\pm i
   \theta}. 
   \end{eqnarray*}

This is the interesting result by Euler where he claimed that all 
rigid body rotations can be written as rotation about one vector
(here $u_1$ by some angle $\theta$).

2. **Eigenvalues of a reflection.** If we repeat all the steps above for a
   reflection we find that now

   \begin{eqnarray*}   B^{-1}A B = \left (   \begin{array}{ccc}
       1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & \cos 2 \theta & \sin 2 \theta \\
       0 & \sin 2 \theta & -\cos 2 \theta    \end{array}   \right ) \end{eqnarray*}

   Now
   \begin{eqnarray*}  
    \det ( C - \lambda I)= 0 \implies   -(\cos
   2 \theta  -  \lambda)(\cos 2 \theta + \lambda )  - \sin^2 2 \theta =
   0. 
   \end{eqnarray*} 
   and then

   \begin{eqnarray*} -\sin^2 2 \theta - \cos^2 2 \theta + \lambda^2 =0
   \end{eqnarray*} and from here

   \begin{eqnarray*}   \lambda =  \pm 1. \end{eqnarray*}
   .

Please see the following reference which I used for this answer:
[Orthogonal Matrices](https://www2.bc.edu/mark-reeder/Linalg17.pdf)

Comment: Can you explain why $det(A^{T}-I) = det(A-I)$

Comment: The link you have provided is not working. Can you please give the new link?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad  : I appreciate your remark.  I updated the link, it was changed.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken again, though archive.org has a saved copy of the previous link https://web.archive.org/web/20150206015748/www2.bc.edu/~reederma/Linalg17.pdf

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, so can I say that the eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices are real iff it produces a pure reflection?

Comment: @DatBoi : I would say no.  Take a Householder transformation in 2D. This is a reflection with eigenvalues 1 and -1. Now a rotation in 2D has eigenvalues exp(i theta). If theta=n*pi, then you get eigenvalues 1, and -1, but these are not reflections, this are rotations. If you include in the concept of reflections those with respect to the origin. Then yes, all eigenvalues 1 and -1 are reflections and vice-versa.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Never thought about considering these reflections about origin. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

Both statements are false as currently written. The following matrix serves as a counter-example for both.
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}\cos 1 & -\sin 1 \\ \sin 1 & \cos 1\end{pmatrix}$$

The first statement needs to be modified so that the matrix has all real eigenvalues, otherwise it is false as noted by Algebraic Pavel in the comments. Let us express an arbitrary non-zero vector $\mathbf{b}$ in polar form
$$\mathbf{b} = r\begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi \\ \sin\phi \end{pmatrix}$$
Then for the above matrix $R$, we get
$$\mathbf{b}^\mathrm{T}R\mathbf{b}= r^2\left( \cos(\phi + 1)\cos\phi + \sin(\phi+1)\sin\phi\right) = r^2\cos 1 > 0
$$
The eigenvalues are both complex however. If we assume that all eigenvalues are real, then the arguments given by TooOldForMath and gaoxinge works fine.

The second statement should say that the *determinant* of an orthogonal matrix is $\pm 1$ and not the eigenvalues themselves. $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, but its eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i}$.

The eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix needs to have *modulus* one. If the eigenvalues happen to be real, then they are forced to be $\pm 1$. Otherwise though, they are free to lie anywhere on the unit circle.